# Avoid Asynchronous invocation from one lambda to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 2 lambda functions ('A' & 'B'), on success condition of lambda 'A' I asynchronously invoke lambda 'B'. Till here it's a working solution for me. 
However what I see is there are certain business conditions I might want to avoid asynchronously invoking lambda 'B' from lambda 'A', how can I achieve that?

For e.g lambda 'A' creates a file in s3, that time I would want lambda 'B' to start working on it and hence asynchronously invoke it . And if lambda 'A' did not create any file in s3, then avoid event of asynchronously invoking lambda 'B'.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use [S3 notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)? If A creates file is S3, S3 notification on a PUT event will trigger automatically lambda B. Obviously, if there is no PUT event due to A not creating a file, lambda B is not triggered.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, actually this is not the only condition there are few more, where I might want to avoid. Just wanted to know if there is some sort of custom response that I can send etc.?

Comment: I would consider decapling your lambdas, and "joining" them using SNS or SQS. If lambda A pushes messages to SNS/SQS,  lambda B gets automatically triggered to process them. You can have few SQS queues, which will hold different types of messages from A, addressed to different consumer (Bs) lambdas. There are several possibilities. Without more details, its difficult to provide more info.

Comment: Sure @Martin, do you mean I have more control programatically to push or not to push to my custom SQS ?

Comment: Yes exactly. And since the lambdas are de-coupled, they are easier to manage, troubleshoot and are more aligned with notion of cloud computing.